# How to write this logic, made in C#, in Java? What the types of the returns in C#?

Tags: java, c#, spring

I have an C# API and just need to port it to Spring API (Java), but I'm having trouble with some logics of C# language.
Here's both codes in C# and Java.

C# (the important is the method [Route("ClienteSemSaldo")]:

```
    namespace Web.Api.Rest.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    public class RcClienteController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IRcClienteService _service;
        private readonly IRcClienteProdutoService _serviceProduto;
        private string _userId;
        private string _userTipo;
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(RcClienteController));

        public RcClienteController(IRcClienteService service, IRcClienteProdutoService serviceProduto)
        {
            _service = service;
            _serviceProduto = serviceProduto;
            _userTipo = "E";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(RcCliente), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]string cliente)
        {
            try
            {
                _userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                var t = await _service.BuscarCliente(_userId, _userTipo, cliente);
                return Ok(t);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("ClienteSemSaldo")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(RcCliente), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ClienteSemSaldo()
        {
            try
            {
                _userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                var posicoes = await _serviceProduto.BuscarClienteProduto(_userId, _userTipo, null, null);
                var clientes = await _service.BuscarCliente(_userId, _userTipo, null);

                var t = clientes.Where(a => !posicoes.Any(b => b.ClienteId == a.ClienteId)).ToList();
                return Ok(t);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Java (the important is the method getClienteSemSaldo):

```
@RequestMapping("/customer")
@RestController
public class CustomerController implements ICustomerController{

    private final String _userTipo = "E";

    @Autowired
    private ICustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    private ICustomerProductService customerProductService;


    @GetMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerResponse>> getCliente(@RequestParam String cliente) throws Exception {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String idUser = authentication.getName();

        List<CustomerResponse> lista = customerService.getCliente(cliente, idUser, _userTipo);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomerResponse>>(lista, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/withoutbalance", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerProductResponse>> getClienteSemSaldo() throws Exception {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String idUser = authentication.getName();

        List<CustomerProductResponse> posicoes = customerProductService.getClienteProduto(null, idUser, _userTipo, null);
        List<CustomerResponse> clientes = customerService.getCliente(null, idUser, _userTipo);

        List<CustomerProductResponse> lista = posicoes.stream()
                                        .filter(a -> !posicoes.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.clienteId == a.clienteId))
                                        //.map(b -> new CustomerProductResponse())
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomerProductResponse>>(lista, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

So the method getClienteSemSaldo must return

```
List<CustomerProductResponse>
```

And not

```
List<CustomerResponse>
```

Right? How to do that?

Comment: Change the return type of `getClienteSemSaldo` method to `List<CustomerResponse>` in both `CustomerController` and `ICustomerController`. And write the logic in the method to create and populate `List<CustomerResponse>` and return

Comment: There's a subtle but significant difference in your queries between C# and Java. Your C# code is applying `Where` to the result of `BuscarCliente`. In your Java code, you are applying `filter` to the result of `getClienteProduto`. If I got it right, `getClienteProduto` is the same as `BuscarClienteProduto` and not `BuscarCliente`. So, to be the same thing, you should apply `filter` to `clientes` and not to `posicoes`. This will return `List<CustomerResponse>`, but that's exactly equivalent to what your C# code is returning.

Answer (score 0):

I have analysed your code and I am a little bit confused. Your method getClienteSemSaldo() returns type of ResponseEntity> and that is the type you return at the end of the method. You use ResponseEntity class constructor with generic argument type and pass "lista" list which was created from filtered posicoes list. That means, they are the same type (List< CustomerProductResponse >). Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, but a List of what? CustomerProductResponse or CustomerResponse?

Comment: This part:   var t = clientes.Where(a => !posicoes.Any(b => b.ClienteId == a.ClienteId)).ToList(); returns a list of clients except those which Id is in posicoes. It should be of type RcCliente but actually it will be of type List<RcCliente>

Comment: List of type <CustomerProductResponse>  because method filter() doesn't change source list type. posicoes.stream().filter(...).collect(...) returns list of the same type as posicoes